# Setting NavigationController.Viewcontrollers crashing (with custom transitions)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, transition

So this is my viewcontroller hierarchy:

```
-RootVC
 -MapVC
  -VC0
  -VC1
  -VC2
```

The app starts of by pushing @[Root, MapVC] to the view controller -- All good. 
Then, my goal is to have the Map loaded (therefore, I don't want to pop the MapVC) while changing between the four main VCs (MapVC, VC0, VC1, VC2).

To do this, I use the following code:

```
   -(void)presentViewController:(NSString*)viewControllerIdentifier{
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerIdentifier];

    if (![[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] count]-1] isKindOfClass:[vc class]]){

        NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self navigationController] viewControllers]];
        if (![[viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[LLMapViewController class]]) {
        [viewControllers removeLastObject];
        }
        [viewControllers addObject:vc];
        [[self navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
        }
}

-(void)presentViewController0:(NSNotification*)notif{
        [self presentViewController:[notif name]];
}
```

--
Method to present the map:

```
-(void)presentMapViewController:(NSNotification*)notif{
    if (![[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] count]-1] isKindOfClass:[LLMapViewController class]]){
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Well, it works well if I don't animate this transitions.
Also, when I do the following actions everything works well

```
App Launches:
->Root 
 ->MapVC

ACTIONS: 
0: Select VC0
->Root
 ->MapVC
  ->VC0

1: Select VC1 (Pops VC0 and pushes VC1, as you can see in the code above)
->Root
 ->MapVC
  ->VC1

2: Select MapVC (Pops VC1)
->Root
 ->MapVC
```

The problem is when I try to push another VC having the MapVC as main VC:

```
3: Select VC0
->Root
 ->Map
....
```

**CRASH!**

It doesn't show any consistent error.
Sometimes it doesn't show any error and sometimes it shows errors like these:

```
Example 1: 
-[NSLayoutConstraint navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:]:

Example 2: 
-[UILabel navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:]:
```

But it always highlights the part when I am setting the navigationcontroller's viewcontrollers .

**MY PROBLEM:** I have spent around 8 hours trying to fix this. I have no more ideas on how to debug this. 
Can anyone **please** help me?

P.S. I am using custom transitions to push/pop the controllers.
Here's additional code:

```
-(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC {

    LLMenuAnimation *animationController = [[LLMenuAnimation alloc] initWithNavigationController:self.navigationController];
    switch (operation) {
        case UINavigationControllerOperationPush:
            animationController.type = AnimationTypePush;
            return  animationController;
        case UINavigationControllerOperationPop:
            animationController.type = AnimationTypePop;
            return animationController;
        default:
            NSLog(@"OTHER OPERATION");
            return nil;

    }


}
```

--

```
#pragma mark - Animated Transitioning

-(NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 0.2;
}

-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    //Get references to the view hierarchy
    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    if (self.type == AnimationTypePush) {
        //Add 'to' view to the hierarchy with 0.5 scale

        toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);


        [containerView insertSubview:toViewController.view aboveSubview:fromViewController.view];

        //Scale the 'to' view to to its final position
        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
            //            toViewController.view.frame = fromViewController.view.frame;
            toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
    } else if (self.type == AnimationTypePop) {
        //Add 'to' view to the hierarchy
        [containerView insertSubview:toViewController.view belowSubview:fromViewController.view];

        //Scale the 'from' view down 
        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
            fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you don't want to pop MapVC? I also understand that VCs (VC1,2,3) can access each other directly?

Comment: So the map does not load/render more than once. No, they can't. I have a drawer menu in the root vc

Comment: But what's wrong with the map loading more than once? iOS will take care of it and it will be 'cached' and loaded much faster the next time you present this VC.

Comment: Yes but it would be a worse experience for the user

Comment: I was taking a look on the crash, and it looks like (UILabel) & (NSLayoutConstraint) are calling navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:] The question is: Are you sure you're setting up the correct delegate?

Comment: I believe so. They are set on the viewdidload method (inherited from a baseviewcontroller)

Comment: Where did you set navigationController's delegate? In baseviewcontroller? If so, does LLMapViewController inherits from baseviewcontroller?

Comment: Yes and yes , all correct

Comment: I think @DaniA could be on to something - looks like the delegate is being dealloc'ed and other objects being created at the same address.  Have you tried with Zombies on, and/or logging the dealloc method of your delegate?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can use UINavigationController the way you are trying to do. If I have understood what you are trying to do, you are wanting to replace the navigationController's viewControllers property from underneath the navigation controller.

By the way, viewControllers property displayed is a copy. This is the way it is defined in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers):

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
```

Your code:

```
        NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self navigationController] viewControllers]];
    if (![[viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[LLMapViewController class]]) {
    [viewControllers removeLastObject];
    }
    [viewControllers addObject:vc];
    [[self navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
    }
```

won't work the way you are expecting. You can push and pop view controllers onto the navigation controller. You can't replace the viewControllers the way you are trying to do.

By the way, the view controller hierarchy you drew in the first few lines of your question above is incomplete. Where is the navigation controller in the hierarchy?

Comment: The rootviewcontroller of the navigationcontroller is the RootVC. 
And yes, I can use it like this. It works perfectly besides that crash which I believe is related to the delegate setting. Still trying to work it out

Comment: @jonypz, I think you are missing something very basic here.  Your statement above does not make any sense whatever. You have not shown any navigationcontroller in the hierarchy. If you are saying that rootVC is a navigationcontroller, then say exactly that and describe your setup accurately. Also, how can it work perfectly and still crash? It does not work the way you think it does. If your implementation works at all, it is by accident and not for its correctness. I won't repeat what I said in my answer; but, I will suggest you read it carefully.

Comment: The relationship segue "root" from the navigation controller is directed to RootVC (RootVC is the first controller of the nav. controller). It works perfectly besides when performing the case above described (if I don't perform that case everything is fine.)

Comment: If your mapvc is already pushed onto the navVC, why not push VCx (VC0, VC1, ...) unto the navVC? You can always pop all the Vcx from the navVC to reveal mapVC. You cannot replace viewControllers property the way you are trying to do in your code. Your navcontroller is already "live" by the time the code that attempts to modify the property executes. It is not correct code. That's likely the reason you are crashing.

Comment: You should read carefully what I wrote above (including comments). I can replace the viewcontrollers using setviewcontroller method, just try to do it, you'll see.

Comment: self.navigationController.viewControllers holds the view controllers currently pushed unto the navVC. When you pop a VC from naVC, you don't need to modify self.navigationController.viewControllers. Don't do [viewControllers removeLastObject]; do popViewController to remove.

Comment: I know. And the result is the same. That is not the root of my problem